# git diff results between PR and branch for a particular directory and its sub-directories

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm looking for some help related to git diff showing results between current branch or PR and main branch, but only for the changes made in a particular directory and its sub-directories. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Many git commands accept paths after a `--` parameter, for example:

```
git diff <main>..<pr_branch> -- <path/to/show>
```

To compare the current branch you can replace `<pr_branch>` with `HEAD`, or omit it, like so:

```
git diff main.. -- path/to/show
```